# Download full html page with CSV export plugin

Tags: php, plugin-development, csv

I am making a csv exporter plugin for my own need. But the problem I have is that, it download whole page as html when I click Export button. Here is my code. Please help me to slove this problem. This script work perfectly as a php application. Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
/*
    CSV Exporter

*/

add_action('admin_menu','jsrmsp_csv_export_menu');

add_action('admin_init','jsrmsp_csv_export_main');

/* Csv Export Menu */

function jsrmsp_csv_export_menu(){

    add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=jsrmsp_sr', 'Export CSV', 'Export CSV', 'manage_options', 'jsrmsp_csv_export_page', 'jsrmsp_csv_export_admin_page' );

}


function jsrmsp_csv_export_main(){
    if( isset( $_POST['csves'] ) ){
        /* CSV Exporter function */

        // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
        //header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-type: application/csv');


        //header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
        //header('Pragma: no-cache');
        //header('Expires: 0');

        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

        // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
        $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        // output the column headings
        fputcsv($output, array('Name', 'Profession', 'Phone'));

        // fetch the data
        mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        mysql_select_db('csv-exporter');
        $rows = mysql_query('SELECT name,profession,phone FROM records');

        // loop over the rows, outputting them
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
}


function jsrmsp_csv_export_admin_page() { ?>


    <div class="wrap">
        <!-- Some inline style -->
        <style type="text/css">
            .jsrmsp-m-title {
              margin: 0 !important;
              padding: 8px 12px !important;
            }

            .csvcol {
              float: left;
              width: 25%;
            }
        </style>

        <?php
            // Check form is submited

            if( isset( $_POST['csves'] ) ){
                jsrmsp_csv_export_main();
            ?>
                <div id="jsrmsp-imload" class="updated fade">

                    <p><img style="height: 15px; vertical-align: middle;" src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__); ?>../assets/images/loader.gif" alt="" />Please wait...</p>

                </div>
            <?php }
        ?>


    </div><!-- end wrap -->

    <div class="wrap">
        <h2><?php _e('Export CSV'); ?></h2>

        <!-- Ajax Response Message -->
        <div class="ajax-response-message">

        </div>

        <div id="dashboard-widgets-wrap">
            <div class="metabox-holder" id="dashboard-widgets">

                <div id="postbox-container" class="postbox-container">
                    <div id="side-sortables" class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable"><div style="display: block;" id="dashboard_quick_press" class="postbox ">
                    <div class="handlediv"><br></div><h3 class="hndle jsrmsp-m-title" style="cursor: default;"><span><span class="hide-if-no-js">Export Csv File</span></span></h3>
                    <div style="overflow: hidden;" class="inside">

                        <form id="jsrmsp-export" class="jsrmsp-import" action="" method="post">

                            <div style="margin: 10px 0; overflow: hidden;" class="input-text-wrap">
                                <div class="csvcol">
                                    <?php
                                        // Exam Class term
                                        $terms = get_terms('classes');
                                        if(!empty($terms) &&!is_wp_error($terms)) { ?>
                                            <select name="class" id="class" required>
                                            <option value=""><?php _e('Select Exam','jsrmsp-td'); ?></option>';
                                            <?php

                                                foreach($terms as $term) {
                                                    echo '<option value="'.$term->name.'">'.$term->name.'</option>';
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                                </select>
                                        <?php }
                                    ?>
                                </div>

                                <div class="csvcol">
                                    <?php
                                        // Exam Year Term
                                        $terms = get_terms('years');
                                        if(!empty($terms) &&!is_wp_error($terms)) { ?>
                                            <select name="year" id="year" required>
                                            <option value=""><?php _e('Select Year','jsrmsp-td'); ?></option>
                                            <?php
                                                foreach($terms as $term) {
                                                    echo '<option value="'.$term->name.'">'.$term->name.'</option>';
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                            </select>
                                        <?php }
                                    ?>
                                </div>

                                <div class="csvcol">
                                    <?php
                                        // Exam Section Term
                                        $terms = get_terms('sections');
                                        if(!empty($terms) &&!is_wp_error($terms)) { ?>
                                            <select name="section" id="section">
                                            <option value=""><?php _e('Select Section','jsrmsp-td'); ?></option>
                                            <?php
                                                foreach($terms as $term) {
                                                    echo '<option value="'.$term->name.'">'.$term->name.'</option>';
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                            </select>
                                        <?php }
                                    ?>
                                </div>

                                <div class="csvcol">
                                    <?php
                                        // Exam Groups Term
                                        $terms = get_terms('groups');
                                        if(!empty($terms) &&!is_wp_error($terms)) { ?>
                                            <select name="group" id="group">
                                            <option value=""><?php _e('Select Group','jsrmsp-td'); ?></option>
                                            <?php
                                                foreach($terms as $term) {
                                                    echo '<option value="'.$term->name.'">'.$term->name.'</option>';
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                            </select>
                                        <?php }
                                    ?>
                                </div>

                            </div>



                            <p class="submit">
                                <input name="csves" id="csves" class="button button-primary" value="Export" type="submit">
                            </p>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>



    </div>

<?php }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you do not `die` after you generate the CSV which meas that wordpress will continue to generate whatever is the relevant admin HTML after it had generated the CSV.

Comment: Ha ha ha, "you do not `die`" - should've said pun intended ;)